# Table check box just for one section objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a uiTableView with 3 sections and different rows, I want to add check box JUST to my third sections,

I create custom cell and I linke img and label

like this picture:

![enter image description here][1]

and my code for custom cell is :

**.h**

```
: UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *checkBox;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *absenceCode;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize checkBox;
@synthesize absenceCode;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
      checkBox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptycheck-box.png"];
}
return self;
}
```

@end

**and code for UITableViewController
viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


NSString *staKey = @"Start";
NSString *endKey = @"End";
NSString *absKey= @"Absence";

[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Time: 08:00 Date: Fri,3 Aug, 2012", nil] forKey:staKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Time: 17:57 Date: Fri,3 Aug, 2012", nil] forKey:endKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red",@"Black",@"Blue", nil] forKey:absKey];


[keys addObject:staKey];
[keys addObject:endKey];
[keys addObject:absKey];


[self setSectionKeys:keys];
[self setSectionContents:contents];
```

}

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

CheckBoxTableViewCell *cell = (CheckBoxTableViewCell*)[tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckBoxTableViewCell"];

        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptycheck-box.png"];




cell.checkBox.image = image;
cell.absenceCode.text =@"Redddd";
cell.text =contentForThisRow;
return cell;

 }
```

would you please help me 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks more like a view than a table view. Any reason why you don't just create a custom view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do what you want.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]; 
    NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key]; 
    NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 

    if (indexPath.section != 2) {
            //Set up default cell here.
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
            cell.textLabel.text =contentForThisRow;
            return cell;
    }
    else {
            CheckBoxTableViewCell *cell = (CheckBoxTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckBoxTableViewCell"];

            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptycheck-box.png"];
            cell.checkBox.image = image;
            cell.absenceCode.text =@"Redddd";
            return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move return into both if cases, be sure to actually set up the cell in the first case (UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];) As for the warning, you should have been getting that before too. Change it to cell.textLabel.text = contentForThisRow;

Comment: one more question, do you know how can I added swich between check box and unmark box , I have 2 picture for them

Comment: That would go in your didSelectRowAtIndex method. You would get the selected row, and change the image as required.